# How to let users sign in with LinkedIn on Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, linkedin-api, flask-login

I'm building a website using the (awesome) Python [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and I now want to let users log in with their LinkedIn account. I managed to display the LinkedIn login button after which I can return some information from the user on the client side:

```
<script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="loadData"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadData() {
        IN.API.Profile("me")
            .fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl","headline"])
            .result(function(result) {
                profile = result.values[0];
                profHTML += "<img src=\"" + profile.pictureUrl + "\">";
                profHTML += "<a href=\"" + profile.publicProfileUrl + "\">";
                profHTML += profile.firstName + " " + profile.lastName + "</a>";
            $("#profile").html(profHTML);
        });
    }
</script>
<div id="profile"></div>
```

This displays my profile picture and my first and last name. So far so good. But how do I know this on the server side? Do I create an API call to which I send a json with all the LinkedIn-information of the user? I can then create a user account in my DB and log the user in with [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Or is there another more logical way of doing this?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [LinkedIn Developer docs](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication)? OAuth2 is the supported auth method from their side.  You may want to take a look at the flask OAuth lib too: https://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for hinting me in the right direction. I now see that the LinkedIn login Javascript is just a simple implementation, but not really the most extensive one. In the end I used this example to get what I want: https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/blob/master/example/linkedin.py